# Warning: require_once(/home/onetwo/public_html/wp-config.php):

Tags: errors

after changing php version on godaddy it started giving these error on wordpress any help highly appriciated.

http://www.two.com.pk

> Warning: require_once(/home/onetwo/public_html/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/onetwo/public_html/wp-load.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/onetwo/public_html/wp-config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/onetwo/public_html/wp-load.php on line 37

Comment: Is the file available in the path listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact GoDaddy customer support and ask them to check file permissions for your site.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of struggle i got fixed by changing the root directory permission to 755